# Was the PIXI.Shader Class (re)moved in PIXI Version 7

Tags: javascript, shader, pixi.js

I want to use the following tutorial for my project:
https://codepen.io/ivanpopelyshev/pen/jOWLjKd

```
const width = window.innerWidth;
const height = window.innerHeight;

const app = new PIXI.Application({ width, height});
document.body.appendChild(app.view);

const shaderCode = document.getElementById("fragShader").innerHTML;

//Our textures are up on github
var textureURL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tutsplus/Beginners-Guide-to-Shaders/master/Part3/images/blocks.JPG"
var normalURL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tutsplus/Beginners-Guide-to-Shaders/master/Part3/normal_maps/blocks_normal.JPG"

//Load in the texture and the normal
var texture = PIXI.Texture.from(textureURL);
var normal = PIXI.Texture.from(normalURL);


//Set up the uniforms we'll send to our share
//More info on uniform types: https://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/ShaderMaterial
var uniforms = {
  tex : texture,//The texture
  norm: normal,//Normal
  res : new Float32Array([window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight]),//Keeps the resolution
  light: new Float32Array(4),//Our light source, we will use the 3 numbers as have x,y and height away from the screen. 4th value is whether the light is on or not
}
//We stick our shader onto a 2d plane big enough to fill the screen

const material = new PIXI.Shader.from(null, shaderCode, uniforms)
const geometry = new PIXI.Geometry()
geometry.addIndex([0,1,2,0,2,3])
geometry.addAttribute('aVertexPosition', // the attribute name
        [0, 0, width, 0, width, height, 0, height], // x, y
        2);
//those are UV's in default vertex shader
geometry.addAttribute('aTextureCoord', // the attribute name
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], // x, y
        2)
const mesh = new PIXI.Mesh( geometry,material );
//Add it to the scene
// scene.add( sprite );
app.stage.addChild(mesh)

uniforms.light[2] = 0.3;//How high up our light source should be
uniforms.light[3] = 1.0;//Turn light on

mesh.interactive = true;
mesh.on('mousemove', (event) => {
    // coords are event.data.global, but we transform them 
    // in case you move mesh somewhere else (position, scale)
    const point = event.data.getLocalPosition(mesh);
  //Update the light source to follow our mouse
  uniforms.light[0] = point.x / width;
  uniforms.light[1] = point.y / height;
});

mesh.on('mousedown', (event) => {
  if(uniforms.light[3])
     uniforms.light[3] = 0.0;
  else uniforms.light[3] = 1.0;
})
```

However, it does not work anymore as soon as I use the latest Version 7 of pixi.js.

It says "Uncaught TypeError: PIXI.Shader.from is not a constructor". But when I read the docs I still see the PIXI.Shader.from function unchanged.

Does anyone know what has changed that this does not work anymore?

Answer (score 0):

I simply had to remove the "new" in "const material = new PIXI.Shader.from(null, shaderCode, uniforms)" and the shader is working now...